# How do I give permissions for the nether to my users?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I have been searching everywhere for just the permissions I need to give my users so they can build/break stuff in the nether. Right now whenever someone enters the nether he gets a message stating something like: all your privilege have been deactivated because you teleported to a new world. 
I am using permissions bukkit.
Here is my config.yml file:

```
   users:
    user1:
        groups:
        - user
groups:
    default:
        permissions:
            permissions.build: true
    admin:
        permissions:
            permissions.*: true
        inheritance:
        - user
    user:
        permissions:
            permissions.build: true
            admincmd.tp.to: true
            simplechestlock.lock: true
            blockdoor.*: true
            blockdoor.player: true
            blockdoor.link: true
            blockdoor.player.*: true
            blockdoor.link.*: true
            admincmd.time.day: true
            admincmd.time.set: true
            catacombs.admin: true
            electricraft.build.*: true
            electricraft.destroy.*: true
            electricraft.damage.*: true
            electricraft.teleport.lift: true
            electricraft.bucket.*: true
        worlds:
            creative:
                coolplugin.item: true
        inheritance:
        - default
messages:
    build: '&cYou do not have permission to build here.'
```

edit: Here is the list of plugins. Not that much.
AdminCmd
BlockDoor
Catacombs
Electricraft
PermissionsBukkit
PluginMetrics
SimpleChestLock

Comment: This config should work across all worlds. Could you post a list of plugins you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the sub-group "worlds:". This most likely governs what the group can do in said world. Try typing the name of the nether file (by default it is world_nether) in the format shown with "creative". Then add the node "permission.build: true" along with anything you would allow them to do in the nether.

Sorry if this does not work as I used a different permissions plugin in my limited server hosting days.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a separate config file for the Nether. I had this problem on a server I administrated, and we had to copy the World config into the Nether config for it to work. This was, however, on a Multicraft server, so it's possible that it had changed the layout.

Answer (score -2):

```
users:
    user1:
        groups:
        - us887er
groups:
    default: 
        permissions:
            permissions.build: true
    admin189993666846..90674351526plc66e3jng3:
        permissions:
            permissions.*: true
        inheritance:
        - user
    user:
        permissions:
            permissions.build: true
            admincmd.tp.to: true
            simplechestlock.lock: true
            blockdoor.*: true
            blockdoor.player: true
            blockdoor.link: true
            blockdoor.player.*: true
            blockdoor.link.*: true
            admincmd.time.day: true
            admincmd.time.set: true
            catacombs.admin: true
            electricraft.build.*: true
            electricraft.destroy.*: true
            electricrasdaft.damage.*: true
            electricraft.teleport.lift: true
            electricraft.bucket.*: true
        worlds:
            creative:
                coolplug9926in.item: true
        inheritance:
        - default
messages:
    build: '&cYou do not frebcghave permission to build here.
```

Comment: I fixed the formatting so this can be read more easily. It's still a bit much, though. Can you give any details as to what this is doing? Is all of this necessary or are there specific parts that are especially pertinent to the question?